# Какой внешний аккумулятор подойдет для питания Wi-Fi роутер Mikrotik RBD52G-5HacD2HnD-TC?

Tags: роутер

Имеется [Wi-Fi роутер Mikrotik RBD52G-5HacD2HnD-TC](https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/470d04e5154f3330/wi-fi-router-mikrotik-rbd52g-5hacd2hnd-tc/). К нему подключены камеры видеонаблюдения. Ночью выключается электричество в офисах, кроме питания на камеры. Получается, что камеры работают и записывают, но в онлайн режиме недоступны, т.к. роутер выключен. Утром же, когда включается роутер, камеры синхронизируются и есть записи видеонаблюдения ночью.

Пришли к выводу, что необходимо приобрести внешний аккумулятор, к которому можно подключить роутер, чтобы он работал ночью и доступ к камерам был круглосуточно.
Нашел три варианта внешних аккумуляторов:

1. Аккумулятор [cactus CS-PBHTBP-20800](https://market.yandex.ru/product--akkumuliator-cactus-cs-pbhtbp-20800/103390265?track=tabs)
2. Аккумулятор [RAVPower RP-PB054 20100mAh](https://market.yandex.ru/product--akkumuliator-ravpower-rp-pb054-20100mah/1721178755?track=tabs)
3. Аккумулятор [INTERSTEP PST-150PD](https://market.yandex.ru/product--akkumuliator-interstep-pst-150pd/491241033?nid=56035&show-uid=15965475701910798631916002&context=search&lr=35&text=%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D1%81%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Хотелось бы узнать, хватит ли заряда какого-либо из этих аккумуляторов, примерно, на 12-13 часов без подключения к сети?

Comment: А почему питание на камеры не выключается ? Видимо они висят на отдельной, не отключаемой линии питания ... лучше подведите эту же линию к роутеру

Comment: @Mike, да, они подключены к другой линии. Была мысль вызвать электриков и провести розетку от этой линии, но что-то эта мысль затерялась на фоне внешних аккумуляторов. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно описанию, он использует блок питания 24 В / 0,8 А. Соответственно  из трёх перечисленных моделей не годится ни одна, ибо все они отдают только 5 вольт по USB.

Ставьте UPS.

24 В * 0,8 А - это 20 Вт. Чтобы столько держать всю ночь, нужен бесперебойник минимум на 350 ВА. А с учётом перепадов температуры и ежедневного глубокого разряда - я бы брал не менее чем на 600 ВА. И всё равно - если батареи в нём продержатся год, это будет хороший результат.

---

> На этих трех моделях есть разъемы для розетки. Если подключить через розетку к аккумулятору это ведь будет то же самое, что и обычная розетка, верно?

Наивны-ы-ый! Если не написано "выход 220 вольт" - их не будет ни на каком разъёме, вот застрелись!

У последней модели указано (в информации ЯМ):

> совместим с соответствующими блоками питания ноутбуков ASUS, Toshiba, Dell, Lenovo, MSI и др) (не входит в комплект); розетка 220В 140Вт

"Не входит в комплект" запросто может быть "хрен где достанешь"...

Но даже если бы... Даже самый пухлый из указанных аккумуляторов - он на 144 ватт-часа. А нагрузка 20 ватт. 7 часов (это на новом, а через месяц жестокой эксплуатации хорошо если половина останется), и всё погасло.

И ещё - большинство внешних банков питания (внезапно!) не поддерживают одновременные подзарядку от сети и обеспечение питанием внешних устройств, либо одно, либо другое (а у некоторых так и просто контроллер выходит из строя при таком режиме работы). Кто переключать-то будет?

Comment: На этих трех моделях есть разъемы для розетки. Если подключить через розетку к аккумулятору это ведь будет то же самое, что и обычная розетка, верно?

Comment: @SimpleUser Добавил пару слов.

Comment: Не знал об этом, спасибо. Если брать ИБП, то какой Вы бы посоветовали за более-менее невысокую цену?

Comment: @SimpleUser А что мешает запитать роутер, как и камеры, по PoE? от той же коровы, что и камеры. Он умеет...

Comment: Кроме роутера ещё нужно будет запитать медиа-конвертер и протягивать провод к камерам (метров 30 длина). Да и знаний не хватает, как это сделать

Comment: @SimpleUser Ну значит UPS. Дешёвый - не берите, наплачетесь... и обязательно берите такой, который в случае полного разряда батарей самостоятельно включается после восстановления питающего напряжения - далеко не все это делают.

Comment: Для примера, подошел бы такой? https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/0daaac20740b8a5a/ibp-cyberpower-bu-1000/

Comment: Давайте не будем оффтопить - вопрос для RU.SO совершенно неформатный. Берите описание модели, смотрите. не подходит по всем характеристикам - смотрите другой. Ещё правильнее - выбрать вендора, сформировать список требований, и с ними обратиться к дистрибьютору за консультацией по подбору.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за информацию. Будем разбираться в этом

Comment: @Akina форматный

Comment: Такое безумное складывание цифр. ВА зачем запасаете в 250% от максимального потребления? Блок питания уже с запасом, кпд 70 - 150% по вольтамперам достаточно.

Comment: @eri *ВА зачем запасаете в 250% от максимального потребления?* На самом деле тут пропущена информация, что бесперебойники менее 600 ВА практически все оборудованы одной батареей. И на ночь (которая в офисных зданиях запросто может начинаться в 5 вечера и заканчиваться в 10 утра) энергии одной батарейки просто не хватит.

Answer (score 1):

Этот роутер запускается от 9 В до 36В напряжения.

> Max power consumption without attachments 8 W

У меня дома модель чуть помощнее вашей, типичное потребление 3 Ватта при домашнем использовании. При максимальной загрузке роутер будет потреблять 8 Ватт.

Бери бесперебоцник для охранки вроде такого https://www.citilink.ru/amp/catalog/photo_and_video/video_observation/cctv_aks/394611/

К нему ставится батарейка свинцовая 7Ач (есть на 12 Ач, но она не влезет в корпус) - хватит на 12 ( 20) часов пока батарейка свежая. Свинцовые батарейки расходник и меняются раз в 2-3 года. https://www.citilink.ru/amp/catalog/photo_and_video/video_observation/cctv_aks/1192600/

Можно взять батарейку получше(но их всеравно менять понадобится) и бесперебойник пофункциональней.

Такие же блоки есть на 24 Вольта, ставится в них 2 батарейки 12*7.

На 5 вольтах тоже запустится, но будет не стабильно. Преобразование через выход 220 вольт излишнее и такие инверторы перегреваются после пары часов бесперебойной работы.

На преобразователях напряжения Вы потеряете 30% мощности - тут роутер питается от самой батарейки. Нет преобразователя - нет потерь.

Comment: *К нему ставится батарейка свинцовая 7Ач - хватит на долго.* 7 ампер-часов. 12 вольт. Одна батарейка. Итого - 84 ватт-часа. И до 20 ватт нагрузки. Даже если забыть про потерю ёмкости и не стопроцентный КПД - 4 часа. Про "надолго" - это так, от балды ляпнуто?

Comment: Потребление роутера в обычном режиме меньше 5 ватт, 20 ватт мощность блока питания. Кпд 100% потому как блок питания на роутере выкидывается и нет инвертора.

Comment: Считая надёжность, мы обязаны брать максимально возможное потребление.

Comment: Максимальное потребление 8, но это если роутер при этом ДДОСить

Comment: 8 ватт - это формально батарейки хватит на 10.5 часов. Реально - через 4 часа она будет сухая, как песок в Сахаре, зато ИБП немножко нагреет воздух.

Comment: Как он нагреет воздух то? это ИБП без преобразователя! Там нечему греться! У меня роутер висел на  батарейке от бесперебойника часов 8 как-то (больше не трабовалось) а пикающего бесперебойника на 600ВА хватает на 2 часа - потом он отрубается в защиту от перегрева инвертора

Comment: @eri, спасибо большое за информацию